# Receiving SMS in J2ME from any port

Tags: java-me, sms

I have made J2ME application for sending and receiving SMS in which message listener is used for listening Incoming message from particular port number.

I want to make SMS Receiver which listen all incoming SMS from anywhere instead from particular port(when I open message connection it ask for port number).

How to implement this??

If possible suggest some source code.

Hope to hear from you soon.

Current code:

```
msgConnection = (MessageConnection)Connector.open("sms://:" + port);
msgConnection.setMessageListener(listener);
void notifyIncomingMessage(MessageConnection conn) { 
  Message message; 
  try { 
    message = conn.receive(); 
  }
}
```

Regards,

Parmanand

Comment: I am working on J2ME and this is part of my code: msgConnection = (MessageConnection)Connector.open("sms://:" + port);
   msgConnection.setMessageListener(listener);void notifyIncomingMessage(MessageConnection conn) {
       Message message;
  try {
   message = conn.receive(); }

Comment: help you add the code to the question.

Comment: Not possible.
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?110549-how-can-find-port-number-of-device-using-J2ME